# swapoff: /swapfile: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, parallels

I am getting below  error while running kubeadm init :

```
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.16.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

`sudo swapoff -a
swapoff: /swapfile: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory`

I am using Ubuntu VM in parallel desktop

`free -m command  output below:
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            979         455          87           1         436         377
Swap:          2047         695        1352`

Answer (score 3):

You do not have enough RAM. Your machine is surviving because you use a swap file (i.e. using your hard drive for extra pseudo-RAM) but that is not supported by Kubernetes so it tried to turn that off which failed because you don't have enough RAM.